# Convert rows in to columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot, pivot-table

```
select ID, Vehicle from table
```

Original result is

```
ID      Vehicle
--------------------
1       Car
1       Bike
1       Scooter
...
1       N.Product
```

Result I am expecting

```
ID    Vehicle1   Vehicle2   Vehicle3  ....VehicleN
-----------------------------------------------------
1     Car         Bike       Scooter       N.Product
```

I went through examples related to pivot, but they didn't help. Any suggestions?

Comment: It's a pivot, for sure. What did you try that "didn't help"?

Comment: If it "didn't help" because you have N columns and most pivot operations are for a known number of columns, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52761674/sql-server-dynamic-pivot-for-an-unknow-number-of-columns - but consider also that converting a variable number of rows into a variable number of columns is usually a bad idea. If it's for reporting purposes, have your front end do it, not the db

Comment: due to limitations at code side, i had to handle it in sql-@CaiusJard

Comment: i tried many examples, spent almost 2 days on this-@CaiusJard

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i did it by creating a temp table then using while loop, add columns and update values

Answer (score 1):

You can use `row_number()` and pivot or conditional aggregation:

```
select id,
       max(case when seqnum = 1 then vehicle end) as vehicle_1,
       max(case when seqnum = 2 then vehicle end) as vehicle_2,
       . . .
       max(case when seqnum = n then vehicle end) as vehicle_n
from (select t.*, 
             row_number() over (partition by id order by vehicle) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
group by id;
```

This assumes that you know the number of columns that you want in the result set.  If that is not the case, you would need to use dynamic SQL -- or aggregate the vehicles into a string.